# How to find all integer division in C# source code

Tags: c#

I have a program with lots of mathematical calculations.  It was converted from VB6, where dividing two integers yields a double.  I need to find all the places where it divides two integers so I can cast the integers to doubles so it will do floating point division instead of integer division.

The best I could come up with was decompile the code using ILDASM and search for 5B.*div in the resulting .il file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions

But there's only a single instruction for all types of division, so it's kind of a pain to verify the types of the arguments in the stack machine.

Is there a more reliable way to find all instances of integer division?

Comment: That's quite a convincing example of why proper tests coverage is important

Comment: A Roslyn extension should be able to access the semantics of the code. Did you try that? What research have you done so far? Was a grep of the IL text the best, or the one thing you tried so far? What _specifically_ are you seeking help with? Stack Overflow isn't an appropriate forum for receiving from-scratch soup-to-nuts solutions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I would consider "Build a Roslyn code analysis extension, here's 2 or 3 lines of relevant code to point you in the right direction" a very good answer to this question, and I would mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Duniho's comment pointed me in the right direction, to use a Roslyn code analyzer.  This code is a great place to start on creating an analyzer:

https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/creating-a-stand-alone-code-analyzer/

The code to do this is really short, start with a Extensibility -> Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool project.

```
void DoAnalysis(string solutionPath)
{
    var ws = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkplace.Create();
    var soln = ws.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
    foreach (var proj in soln.Projects)
    {
        var compile = proj.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
        foreach (var tree in compile.SyntaxTrees)
        {
            var symantic = compile.GetSemanticModel(tree);
            foreach (var divide in tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodesAndSel()
                .Where(i => i.IsKind(SyntaxKind.DivideExpression))
                .OfType<BinaryExpressionSyntax>())
            {
                if (semantic.GetTypeInfo(divide.Left).ConvertedType.Name == "Int32"
                    && semantic.GetTypeInfo(divide.Right).ConvertedType.Name == "Int32")
                {
                     Consel.WriteLine("File " + tree.FilePath + " at " + divide.Span.Start);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```